# 200 response with curl, 403 with python requests

Tags: python, curl, http-status-code-403

I'm simply sending a request to this [url](https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/scottsdale-az-stock-clerk-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,13_IC1133911_KO14,25.htm?src=GD_JOB_AD&rdserp=true&srs=EI_JOBS&jl=1008874519264&ao=1136043&s=21&guid=0000018ab3ad27ccbc470b1f6b275b17&pos=101&t=ESR&vt=w&uido=E2E7DBC4ACD391CABF382B9AEDAFF99C&ea=1&cs=1_f8a82cfa&cb=1695231584675&jobListingId=1008874519264&jrtk=5-yul1-0-1hapqqa33ir2a800-0383467bbae09c6a) using curl and python requests. While it works for curl and gives a 200 response, it doesn't for python. Here's the results I get in both cases:

```
curl --head 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/scottsdale-az-stock-clerk-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,13_IC1133911_KO14,25.htm?src=GD_JOB_AD&rdserp=true&srs=EI_JOBS&jl=1008874519264&ao=1136043&s=21&guid=0000018ab3ad27ccbc470b1f6b275b17&pos=101&t=ESR&vt=w&uido=E2E7DBC4ACD391CABF382B9AEDAFF99C&ea=1&cs=1_f8a82cfa&cb=1695231584675&jobListingId=1008874519264&jrtk=5-yul1-0-1hapqqa33ir2a800-0383467bbae09c6a' \
-H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
--compressed

HTTP/2 200 
date: Wed, 20 Sep 2023 17:59:25 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
cache-control: no-store
```

here's the same using python requests:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

response = requests.get(
    'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/scottsdale-az-stock-clerk-jobs-SRCH_IL.0,13_IC1133911_KO14,25.htm?src=GD_JOB_AD&rdserp=true&srs=EI_JOBS&jl=1008874519264&ao=1136043&s=21&guid=0000018ab3ad27ccbc470b1f6b275b17&pos=101&t=ESR&vt=w&uido=E2E7DBC4ACD391CABF382B9AEDAFF99C&ea=1&cs=1_f8a82cfa&cb=1695231584675&jobListingId=1008874519264&jrtk=5-yul1-0-1hapqqa33ir2a800-0383467bbae09c6a',
    headers=headers,
)
print(response)

<Response [403]>
```

Comment: curl also got `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden` in my test

Comment: I dont Test your url but url Parameter Like foo=bar should be given as and dict for the request Like params={"foo":"bar"} like u did with Headers. Just google "python requests url params"

Comment: @SinanCetinkaya that's weird if you copied the curl from here, I just tried it still gives 200

Comment: @Christoph I'm well aware of the url params that are usually passed as a dict, i already tried that and it doesn't work as well.

Comment: requests are being blocked by the server: `Please help us protect Glassdoor by verifying that you're a real person. We are sorry for the inconvenience.`
if you're trying to scrape that website, neither `curl` nor `requests` will work.